# Getting only the last value from cursor of sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Cursor getting first value as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyy7Y.png)

But returning last value as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlrXu.png).

Code for getting from cursor

```
    BillInfo getContact(String date) {  
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Cursor query

```
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ID, new String[] { KEY_ID,  
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATE }, KEY_DATE + "=?",  
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(date) }, null, null, null, null); 

            BillInfo contact = null ;
```

Array bill type

```
            BillInfo bill[]=null;
            int i=0;
```

Cursor code

```
if (  cursor.moveToFirst() )  {

                    bill=new BillInfo[cursor.getCount()];

                    do {


//Since both are in different classes

                        contact = new BillInfo(cursor.getString(0),  cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));  
                        bill[i]=contact;

                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

                }
                return bill[i];
            }
```

Code for loading the values on click

```
    public void Load1(View v){
                date1=date.getText().toString();
                Doubleme d=new Doubleme(this);
                BillInfo s;

Returning the value from get contact

                s= d.getContact(date1);


                info.append( s.toString());

            }
```

Comment: Where is the value of i (in the cursor iteration) set?

Comment: The description is unclear. You are querying records with a specific date. Are you asking how to get one specific one if there are multiple ones with the same date? If yes, what do you mean with "first"/"last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, the value of i is fixed:

```
int i=0;
```

But inside of the cursor iteration loop you each time override the bill[i] with a new BillInfo reference. No wonder why the line:

```
return bill[i];
```

fetches the last row instead of the first one. I suggest getting rid of the while loop if you only need the first row.